# Time Over 23:59:59 in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, time

In MySQL I can create a table with a time field, and the value can be as high as 838:59:59 (839 hours - 1 second). I just read that in PostgreSQL, the hour field cannot exceed 23:00:00 (24 hours). Is there a way around this? I'm trying to make a simple DB that keeps track of how many hours & minutes were spent doing something, so it'll need to go higher than 23 hours & some minutes. I can do this in MySQL, but I need to use PostgreSQL for this. I Googled, but didn't find what I'm looking for, so I'm hoping I just didn't use the right keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they use the same notation, there's a difference between time of day and elapsed time. Some of their values overlap, but they're different domains. 838 isn't a valid value for an hour if you're talking about a time of day. 838 *is* a valid value for an hour if you're talking about elapsed time.

This distinction leads to two different data types: [timestamp and interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

```
create table intervals (
  ts timestamp primary key,
  ti interval not null
);

insert into intervals values (current_timestamp, '145:23:12');

select *
from intervals;

2011-08-03 21:51:16.837    145:23:12

select extract(hour from ti)
from intervals

145
```

Comment: Now that sounds like it's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Postgres has no "hour field" - it has a few [date/time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) which serve different needs. The type I believe best fits your needs is `INTERVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right, but It should not be an issue to work around.  Would suggest storing the UNIX time integers for when you "punch in" and out again, and then adding the delta to an int field.

This will yield the number of seconds spent, which can be translated trivially into an hours:minutes:seconds format.

The delta (difference) can be calculated by subtracting the start timestamp from the end timestamp.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing it this way if I could, but it sounds like this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Mmn, sorry.  The timestamp paradigm is really easy to work with, though, and can be manipulated with ease from any programming language... that supports integers, I mean.  It'll feel good once you get used to it, and adding set amounts of time is as easy as (pseudocode example) var + (1*60*60), which would add an hour.  Best of luck.

Comment: No, you just need to use the INTERVAL datatype.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a datetime field...  839 hours being something on the order 34.9 days...

Comment: What datetime value would you enter to represent 839 hours, and why on earth would you do that instead of using a data type designed specifically to represent intervals?